# MAMP & localhost email

Tags: email, mamp

how does one go about getting email to work in a default MAMP installation? not sure if this is relevant but im trying to send emails from a codeigniter app and whatever protocol i use (mail, sendmail, or smtp), emails never arrive

anyone?

Answer (score 0):

My ISP is blacklisted so its impossible to send emails from my local server. Check your mail log (/var/log/mail.log) - it may give you some useful information. I usually use google's smtp servers for sending mail during development, and then use mail() on the production server..

Comment: how do you go about using google smtp, you have a link that describes how to set this up? i had no idea this was possible